# Test function with argument as anonymous function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a function that takes an argument that returned from an anonymous function. I tried to test that anonymous function but it's not getting covered.

```
this.validateAllocations(() => {
        this.submitData();
        if (this.state.shed=== "recurring") {
          this.props.history.push("/ga/recommend");
        } else {
          this.props.history.push("/ga/recommend");
        }
      });
```

This is the function what I have, I tried a lot with `jest.spyOn` but not getting covered. in the coverage report.

```
it("test with low balCheck and amount less than 500", () => {
      const validateAllocations = jest.spyOn(
        shallowInstance,
        "validateAllocations"
      );
      validateAllocations.bind({
        state: shallowWrapper.state(),
        setState: jest.spyOn(shallowInstance, "setState"),
      })();
      expect(validateAllocations).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

`shallowInstance` is an instance of the Component.

Comment: *How* did you try to test it? Give a [mre].

Comment: This function is inside a component so what I am doing is creating a spyOn and then doing the test. [Updated the code]

Comment: There's no real code involved in that test. You call a test double of `validateAllocations` with no parameters, the callback you're trying to cover isn't part of the test *at all*. Generally your test seems very tied to the implementation of the component, rather then the behaviour - interfering directly with the component's state is a huge test smell, for example. Without an actual [mre] of the component it's hard to say what the right test is, but in general test React components via their public interface (the props and the DOM).